# How to select second table in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this to get customer name for auto complete function.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT orderr_customer_name FROM orderr WHERE orderr_customer_name LIKE '$queryString%' GROUP by orderr_customer_name LIMIT 10");
                if($query) {
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {

                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->orderr_customer_name.'\');">'.$result->orderr_customer_name.'</li>';
```

How can i Select another table? this is the table i want to use

```
("SELECT customer_name FROM customer WHERE customer_name LIKE '$queryString%' GROUP by customer_name LIMIT 10");
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: Um... Either your question is very unclear, or this a joke. If you want to use another table, you have the SELECT statement right there; you posted it. Are you asking  about SELECTing from **both** tables at the same time?

Comment: Yes, i want to select from 2 table at the same time.

Comment: Did either of the two posted solutions answer your question? If so, please mark the appropriate one as the answer; if not, please further clarify the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into something like that (Note that I can't test it now, this is only a guideline):

```
SELECT orderr.orderr_customer_name, customer.customer_name 
FROM customer INNER JOIN orderr_customer_name ON orderr.orderr_customer_name = customer.customer_name 
WHERE customer_name LIKE '$queryString%' GROUP by customer_name LIMIT 1
```

Pleasy read the doc: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to query and combine the results from two tables through the use of a single query. This can be accomplished rather easily with a `UNION` in MySQL.

```
(SELECT orderr_customer_name AS customer_name FROM orderr WHERE orderr_customer_name LIKE '$queryString%')
UNION
(SELECT customer_name FROM customer WHERE customer_name LIKE '$queryString%')
ORDER BY customer_name LIMIT 10
```

Don't forget to make sure you escape/sanitize `$queryString`, and that you have proper indexes on your tables. Also, in your specific example, it appears you might be duplicating customer names in at least one place; while some applications require this, you may also want to consider normalization - but that's another topic.